# Using nested loops to repeat a function multiple times

Tags: arrays, sas, nested-loops, data-analysis, do-loops

Hi I am a fairly new SAS programmer and trying to use nested do loops to conduct a subtraction function. The aim is to subtract the variables a_1 to a_5 from b_1 using 1 loop and then repeating the process for all of the a_ variables (a_1 to a_4).
I also need to account for missing data and the code I am currently using is giving me all values as missing values.

Code:

```
data test1;
  set test;

  array b [4] b_1 - b_4;
  array c [4] c_1 - c_4;
  array a [5] a_1 - a_5;

  do j=1 to j=4;

    c_j=0;
    if not missing (b_j) then do i = 1 to 5;
      c_j = (0 le (b_j- a (i)) le 30);
       
      if c_j = 1 then leave;
    end;

    if (a_1 - a_5) | b_j = . then c_j = .;
    if c_j=1 then c_j=year(b_j);

  end;

  drop i j;
run;
```

Comment: Please show some example input and what the expected result should be for that input.

Answer (score 0):

To index into an array use `array_name[index]` not `array_name_index`.

```
if not missing( b[j] ) then
```

Note that you don't need to use square brackets: you could also use either curly brackets, `b{j}`,  or regular parentheses, `b(j)`.

The do loop will never execute since the upper bound of zero is less than the starting value of 1.  The value of the expression `j=4` is either going to be true (1) or false (0) depending on the value of J and there is no way J could get the value of 4 by the time the upper bound is determined.  To iterate J from 1 to 4 use:

```
do j=1 to 4;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the result I was looking for.